JetpackCompose Material3 Button border override not working
As the title says: Cannot override the border stroke for my Button composable. Below is my custom Button, how I invoke the composable by passing a border:BorderStroke parameter, and an image showing what it looks like.
@Composable
fun CustomButtonPrimary(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    shape: RoundedCornerShape? = null,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color? = null,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
){
    
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier.height(30.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp, start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp),
        shape = shape ?: MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        enabled = enabled,
        colors = ButtonColors(
            containerColor = color ?: MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
            contentColor = if(color != null) Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.75f) else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
            disabledContainerColor = Color.DarkGray,
            disabledContentColor = Color.White
        ),
        border = border
    ) {
        ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall) {
            content()
        }
    }
    
}

calling the Composable button like this:
CustomButtonPrimary(
    onClick = { ... },
    modifier = modifier
        .widthIn(95.dp, 120.dp)
        .height(20.dp),
    color = if(account.availableFunds <= 0) Color.DarkGray else null,
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red)
) {
    Text(text = btnText)
}

does not over-ride the original border. If you look at the image below. I have a border = Color.Red BEHIND my MaterialTheme coloring.... but I can't remove the green color and just show the red.

I've tried wrapping my Button in a Surface(){} with applied border styling.
I've also tried changing the Button.modifier = modifier.border() property
Scratching my head on this one, any suggestions?

I cannot reproduce the problem, with your code I get a button with a red border. Can you please try to provide a [mre]? Remove everything that isn't essential to demonstrate the problem but make sure it actually is reproducible, so you might need to add some parts of your theme and how you apply it. But please make sure the code you provide is minimal.

Thanks Lev, witodev helped me with it. Will apply your suggestion.

I'm using your code but at compile time it's showing me how you want, with the red border, try to put it in your root of the app, maybe some value is making the border always green.


Will give it a go and see. Mind sharing your the dependencies?

Just tested, you're right. Thanks! Will go from here. Appreciate it!

Yup, mistake on my end, had it wrapped in a box >_<  I think that's my cue for break time!

Noob mistake.... I missed the fact I had this wrapped within a Box() which over-rode my styles. Removing this worked as expected.
Thanks everyone! Accepting witodev's answer.
Box(
    modifier = modifier
      .border(
        1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, 
        RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
      )
) {
   MyCustomButton(){ }
}

